# Looking for an episode from Night Gallery or something where a doctor cuts his guest's legs off

Tags: story-identification

A guy is lost in a city or maybe a wooded area, and he asks to sleep in a house.
When he wakes up, he finds that he has no legs: they were amputated by the house
owner, who is a crazy doctor. Do any of you remember this? Thanks.

Comment: Similar story from Greek myth with Procrustes as the antagonist who lets travellers spend the night but, if they do not fit the bed they are offered, he stretches or cuts off until they do fit.  Not an answer to your question, but an inspiration to it quite possibly.

Comment: I am aware of the story I have been searching for it for a long time also. The victim has psychic abilities. Meets the Doctor at his residence while on a walk in the woods. The Doctor drugs him with wine when he discovers his abilities. The victim wakes in the Doctors house in the bedroom with his legs cut off.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds a little bit like an episode of "Darkroom" from 1981 starring Claude Aikins (hosted by James Coburn) called "Uncle George".

Darkroom (TV series) 
 Bert Haskell 
– Uncle George (1981) … Bert Haskell

The [IMDB Description of Uncle George Episode](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0554718/)

> This is one of the better and most unpredictable episodes of this great series. A couple in maybe their 40s have an elderly uncle living with them. He is not as old as he appears at first though, we later learn he is only about 65. George passes away and the couple are faced with what to do after his death. Uncle George has had a pension check coming that has helped the struggling couple out and they do not want to lose it. The husband has a heart problems. So they set out to find a replacement for him. James Coburn introduces the story and is as cool as he always is. Copies of this are hard to find but if you do find it check it out! Once you find out the truth about "Uncle George" you'll cringe for sure!

[Episode preview](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gHxly6_YX-k)

Answer (score 1):

The Night Gallery episode you're thinking of is named "Marmalade Wine." Hedre's one review of it here: https://davidjuhl.wordpress.com/2013/12/13/night-gallery-story-marmalade-wine-reviewed-here/

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We encourage you to include relevant information from outside sources in the text of your answer. A link may expire, and a good answer should stay valid regardless of conditions elsewhere.